# Turn off slimerJs viewport

Tags: settings, viewport, slimerjs

For some reason i can't use *phantomJs*, which does not have a rendered page view-port.

How can I turn off view-port in *slimerJs*?

one of the solutions is:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = {width: 0; height: 0},
```

but with this I get unwanted pop-ups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn off view-port on Linux. 
You should install xvfb. 
[SlimerJs docs](https://docs.slimerjs.org/current/installation.html#having-a-headless-slimerjs)

Comment: what about OS windows, is there some solution for this operating system?