# How can I prevent slimerjs browser opens when I run a script?

Tags: casperjs, slimerjs

This is not about viewport. The viewport is ok. One thing is the viewport size of the screen, width and height, and another is the graphical interface browser (window), that is opened when you run casperjs test.js --engine=slimerjs.

It's ok that the browser opens when I run casperjs test.js --engine=slimerjs, very useful for testing purposes. But when I stopped  testing and want to do something bigger I don't want that browser window open 10 times or 100 times.

I've been reading a while and couldn't find any in the documentation, google or here.

If this is possible, throw the command, I will be very grateful for that. Thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turn off slimerJs viewport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33142086/turn-off-slimerjs-viewport)

Comment: This is not about viewport. The viewport is ok. One thing is the viewport size of the screen, width and height, and another is the graphical interface browser (window), that is opened when you run casperjs test.js --engine=slimerjs.

Comment: IF I didn't use viewports sizes, I won't get any images sizes when doing casper.capture("image.png"), that is another reason why this is a different question from that.

Comment: It's the same question. The only difference is that the asker thought of a "solution" (reduce the viewport) that didn't work. A good indication that the question is the same is that the answer is *exactly* the same.

Comment: Sure, in that case, that questions has a wrong title. I search before to ask, and what I need has nothing to do with the viewport, as I said I need the viewport, I don't need the window browser of slimerjs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it`s possible, you can hidden window with xvfb util. [How to do it. Docs](http://docs.slimerjs.org/current/installation.html#having-a-headless-slimerjs)

Comment: Thank you! Does work nice, xvfb-run casperjs tests.js --engine=slimerjs . The docs says that any window will be shown, but the memory usage will be the same as if the windows open?

Comment: Xvfb performs all graphical operations in memory without showing any screen output.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same requirement. xvfb (virtual frame buffer) does this work easily
Install xvfb with this command.

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb
```

Then run it using this prefix.

```
xvfb-run -a
```

So run the command like

```
xvfb-run -a casperjs tests.js --engine=slimerjs
```

This will run the application in the headless mode.